# What does the end of this segment of Lucky Channel reference?

Tags: lucky-star

At the end of the Lucky Channel segment in episode 5 of Lucky Star, Akira Kogami, raging because she won't be appearing in the main show despite the introduction of a new cute-little-girl-type character, says to her co-host Minoru Shiraishi:

"You know. Why don't we change Shiraishi Minoru's name to something else? Like Su-"

The segment then ends abruptly.

What, if anything, was this a reference to? What name did she intend on giving him? Googling the quote doesn't help, and I can't find it in the lists of references people have compiled for the series either.

Comment: According to the commens on [NicoNicoDouga](http://nico.ms/sm261486?from=858), it was "Sugita Tomokazu", who voiced *Kyon* in *The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya*. Researching a bit more, Minoru also participated in TMoHS as voice actor of *Taniguchi*, Kyon's classmate. However, I'm still unsure what it refers to, but it seems they both were famous of their ad-lib.